# command execution ordering inside a PowerShell scriptblock

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

I got excited with PowerShell ScriptBlock at first but I was confused recently with its executing ordering inside blocks. For example:

```
$test_block = {
  write-host "show 1"
  ps
  write-host "show 2"
  Get-Date
}
```

The output by calling $test_block.Invoke():

```
show 1
show 2
<result of command 'ps'>
<result of command 'get-date'>
```

Do commands who output something run first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour is because [write-host](http://ss64.com/ps/write-host.html) doesn't put the output on the pipeline.  The other commands are placed on the pipeline so are not output to the screen until the function (invoke) returns.

To get the behaviour I believe you were expecting, use [write-output](http://ss64.com/ps/write-output.html) instead, the results of all the commands will then be returned in the pipeline.

```
$test_block = {
  write-output "show 1"
  ps
  write-output "show 2"
  Get-Date
}

$test_block.Invoke()
```

Answer (score 6):

To complement [David Martin's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19630614/45375):

- Avoiding [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) (which is [often the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/)) in favor of [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output), i.e. outputting to the *success output stream* - rather than *printing to the display* with `Write-Host`<sup>[1]</sup> - solves your immediate problem.
- However, **you could have avoided the problem by using `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) instead of the `.Invoke()` method**:

  ```
    # Invokes the script block and *streams* its output.
    & $test_block
  ```

  - Using **`&` is *generally* preferable**, not just to avoid `.Invoke()`'s collect-all-success-output-stream-first behavior - see next section.

As an aside:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375) describes common problem with *similar symptoms* (success output (pipeline output) appearing *out of order* relative to other streams), although it is *technically unrelated* and also occurs with `&`:

  ```
  # !! The Write-Host output prints FIRST, due to implicit, asynchronous
  # !! table formatting of the [pscustomobject] instance.
  & { [pscustomobject] @{ Foo = 'Bar' }; Write-Host 'Why do I print first?' }
  ```

---

##### Why `&`, not `.Invoke()`, should be used to invoke script blocks (`{ ... }`):

**[Script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) are normally invoked with `&`**, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), in [*argument (parsing) mode*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing) (like cmdlets and external programs), **not via their `.Invoke()` method**, which allows for more familiar syntax; e.g.:

- `& $test_block` rather than `$test_block.Invoke()`
- with arguments: `& $test_block arg1 ...` rather than `$test_block.Invoke(arg1, ...)`

Perhaps more importantly, using this ***operator-based* invocation** syntax (`& { ... } ...` or `. { ... } ...`) has the following **advantages**:

- It **preserves normal *streaming* semantics**, meaning that *success* output (too) is emitted from the script block *as it is being produced*, whereas **`.Invoke()` *collects all success output first***, in a `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]` instance, which it *then* returns - by contrast, the `Write-Host` output goes *straight to the display* in both cases.

  - As a beneficial side effect, your *specific* output-ordering problem goes away, but note that in **PSv5+ there can *generally* still be an output-ordering problem**, although its **cause is unrelated**:
    Implicit *tabular* output (implied `Format-Table`) for output types *without predefined format data* is *asynchronous* in an effort to determine suitable column widths (your specific code happens to only use cmdlets with predefined format data).
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375) for more information; a simple repro:

    ```
     [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 }; Write-Host 'Should print after, but prints first.'
    ```
- It **allows you to pass *named* arguments** (e.g. `-Foo Bar`), whereas `.Invoke()` supports only *positional* (unnamed) ones (e.g. `Bar`).
- It **preserves normal semantics for *script*-terminating errors**:

  ```
  # OK: & throw aborts the entire script; 'after' never prints.
  & { throw 'fatal' }; 'after'

  # !! .Invoke() "eats" the script-terminating error and
  # !! effectively converts it to a *statement*-terminating one.
  # !! Therefore, execution continues, and 'after' prints.
  { throw 'fatal' }.Invoke(); 'after'
  ```
- Additionally, **using *operator*-based invocation gives you the option to use `.`**, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-), in lieu of `&`, so as to run a script block *directly in the caller's scope*, whereas an `.Invoke()` method call *only* runs in a *child* scope (as `&` does):

  ```
  # Dot-sourcing the script block runs it in the caller's scope.      
  . { $foo='bar' }; $foo # -> 'bar'
  ```

**Use of `.Invoke()` is best limited to [*PowerShell SDK*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart) projects** (which are typically C#-based, where use of PowerShell operators isn't an option).

---

<sup>[1] Technically, since PowerShell v5 `Write-Host` outputs to the *information stream* (stream number `6`), which, however, prints to the display by default, while getting ignored in the pipeline and redirections. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65360389/45375) for a juxtaposition of `Write-Host` and `Write-Output`, and why the latter is typically note even needed.</sup>