# Is there a way to set a variable up to place output to stdout or null?

Tags: powershell, null, stdout

I would like to set up a variable in my code that would ultimately define if I'll see some output or not.

- `"hello"` writes to stdout
- `"hello" > $null` supresses output

My idea is something like this:

```
$debugOutputSwitch = $true
$outputVar = $null
if ($debugOutputSwitch){ $outputVar = **STDOUT** }
...
Write-Host "Something I want out anyway"
"Something I might not want on STDOUT" > $outputVar
```

If this general idea is a way to go, then `STDOUT` is what I'm looking for

If this idea is completely wrong...well...then I'm lost

Comment: Why not just use `Write-Debug` and set `$DebugPreference`? (`Continue` to output, `SilentlyContinue` to not.)

Comment: Sounds more like you want `Write-Verbose`, but @JeroenMostert's point stands :)

Comment: Would you be kind enough and provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to read up on are [output streams and redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6) in Powershell. This includes information on all of the different output streams and how to control their relevance using built-in constructs. Just like there are the `Write-Host` and `Write-Output` cmdlets, there are also several others that control which stream to write to.

## About the Output Streams

There are **6** streams in total. Make note of their numbers, because these stream identifiers are used to control which streams to redirect:

- **1** - Success Stream - This stream is used when passing information along the [Powershell Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-6). This is the "default" stream, but can also be written to with `Write-Output`.
- **2** - Error Stream - Errors should be written to this stream. Can be written to with `Write-Error`, accompanied by further error information.
- **3** - Warning Stream - Used to write warning information. Can be written to with
  `Write-Warning`.
- **4** - Verbose Stream - Used to write verbose output. Does not display by default but can be made to display by either setting [`$VerbosePreference = "Continue"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6), or by using the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute on a function or script and passing in the `-Verbose` flag. Write to the verbose stream with `Write-Verbose`.
- **5** - Debug Stream - Used to write to the debug stream, and optionally trigger a breakpoint. Does not display or trigger a breakpoint by default, but can be controlled with the [`$DebugPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6) variable, or by using the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute on a script or function and using the `-Debug` flag. You can write to the debug stream by using the
  `Write-Debug` cmdlet.
- **6** - Information Stream - Can be written to by `Write-Host`. This is the console host output and is not part of the pipeline.

## Redirecting Streams

You can use redirection operators to redirect other streams to the success stream as well. Each stream above has a number associated with it. This is the numeric representation of each stream.

The redirection operators are as follows:

- `>` - Redirect success stream to file (overwrite)
- `#>` - Redirect the `#` stream to file (e.g. `2> somefile.txt`)
- `>>` - Redirect success stream to file (appends, you can also use a numbered stream as with the overwrite file operator)
- `>&1` - Redirect *any* stream to **success** stream (note that unlike the other redirection operators you can *only* redirect **to** the success stream. Using other stream identifiers will result in an error).

Also note that in place of a stream number, you can use `*` which will redirect ***all streams*** at the same time.

Here are some examples of redirecting output from one stream to another (if you're familiar with it, it's somewhat UNIX-y):

```
# Write success stream to file
Write-Output "Here is some text for a file" > .\somefile.txt

# Write error stream to file (you have to first
Write-Error "Some error occurred" 2> .\somefile.txt

# Redirect all error output to the success stream
$myErrorOutput = Write-Error "My error output" 2>&1

# Append all script output streams to a single file
Get-OutputFromAllStreams.ps1 *>> somefile.txt
```

## Output to a File and the Pipeline Simultaneously

You can redirect the output stream to a file and the pipeline at the same time as well, [using the `Tee-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-6). This also works with variables, too:

```
$myString = "My Output" | Tee-Object -FilePath .\somefile.txt
$myString2 = "My Output 2" | Tee-Object -Variable varName
```

## Sample function to show how to use the different `Write-` cmdlets

Note how the following function is decorated with the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute. This is key in making the `-Verbose` and `-Debug` switches work without you having to define them yourself.

```
function Write-DifferentOutputs {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  # These all visible by default but only the output stream is passed down the pipeline
  Write-Output "Output stream"
  Write-Warning "Warning stream"
  Write-Error "Error stream"
  Write-Host "Information stream"

  # These are not visible by default, but are written when the `-Verbose` or `-Debug` flags are passed
  # You can also manually set the $VerbosePreference or $DebugPreference variables to control this without parameters
  Write-Verbose "Verbose stream"
  Write-Debug "Debug stream"
}
```

Call the above function with the `-Verbose` or `-Debug` switches to see how the behavior differs, and also call it with neither flag.

## Redirecting output to `$null` if you really need to

If there is output that you never want to see or for some other reason using the `Write-` cmdlets to write to the `Verbose` or `Debug` streams isn't an option, you can still redirect output to `$null` or make use of the `Out-Null` cmdlet. Recall the numbered streams at the top of this answer, they will be referenced here:

### Using redirection

```
# Don't forget that *> redirects ALL streams, and may be what you want
Write-Output 'Success Stream' > $null
Write-Error 'Error Stream' 2> $null
Write-Warning 'Warning Stream' 3> $null
Write-Verbose 'Verbose Stream' 4> $null
Write-Debug 'Debug Stream' 5> $null
Write-Host 'Information Stream (yes you can suppress/redirect me)' 6> $null
```

You can also redirect target streams per command: The following example (using the earlier `Write-DifferentOutputs` function) redirects all streams *except* for the Error and Success streams:

> **Note:** You are not limited to redirecting targeted streams only to `$null`.

```
Write-DifferentOutputs 6>$null 5>$null 4>$null 3>$null
```

### Using `Out-Null`

Remember, you can redirect other streams to the success stream by redirecting the output to `&1`.

```
# Remember, to pass information on the pipeline
# it MUST be on the success stream first

# Don't forget that *> redirects ALL streams, and may be what you want
Write-Output 'Success Stream' | Out-Null
Write-Error 'Error Stream' 2>&1 | Out-Null
Write-Warning 'Warning Stream' 3>&1 | Out-Null
Write-Verbose 'Verbose Stream' 4>&1 | Out-Null
Write-Debug 'Debug Stream' 5>&1 | Out-Null
Write-Host 'Information Stream (yes you can suppress/redirect me)' 6>&1 | Out-Null
```

### When using `Out-Host` is appropriate ("Don't Cross the Streams")

> **Warning:** Unlike *`Write-Host`*, `Out-Host` does not output to the information stream. Instead, it outputs directly to the host console. This makes redirection of anything written directly to `Out-Host` impossible short of using `Start-Transcript` or using a custom PowerShell host. Note that information written to the console host is still visible to external applications which may be watching the output of PowerShell, as ultimately even
> `Out-Host` output makes it to STDOUT.

Calling yourself `Out-Host` is *usually* redundant. By default, PowerShell sends all unassigned output on the success stream here via way of the `Out-Default` cmdlet (which you should ***never*** call
`Out-Default` directly). That said, one useful invocation of `Out-Host` is to synchronously output formatted object data to the console:

> **Note:** You can redirect information from other output streams and output to `Out-Host` as well, but there is no reason to do so. Object data will only remain intact on the success stream, the other streams will first convert an object to its `ToString()` representation prior to redirection. This is also why piping the object to `Out-Host` in this case is preferable to `Write-Host`.

```
Get-Process msedge | Out-Host
```

One of the caveats of the different output streams is that there is no synchronicity between streams. *Normally* this is not an issue as PowerShell executes instructions line by line in order, and with the exception of `Write-Output` success stream this is not a problem with the other streams. However, many types will have a computed *for-display* attribute which is computed *asynchronously* from the script execution before the information is sent to `Out-Default`.

**This can result in the displayed object data being intermingled with other output streams which are written to the console host**. In some cases, this can even result in loss of information written to the console. "Crossing the streams", if you will, as it pertains to how the rendered output may look.

Consider the following example and output. This does not showcase the streams intermingling, but consider the trouble you would have parsing the output externally if `` Write-Host "end `n" `` were written in the middle of the table:

```
Write-Host "start `n"

Get-LocalUser

Write-Host "end `n"
```

And the output:

```
start


end

Name               Enabled Description
----               ------- -----------
Administrator      True
DefaultAccount     False   A user account managed by the system.
Disabled           False   Built-in account for guest access to the computer/domain
```

In particular this is problematic for types which define a *table format* that must *calculate the column width* before sending the formatted data to `Out-Host` for display. Types which pre-define the table width or do not format output as a table at all do not have this problem. `Out-Default` can take up to *300ms* to calculate column width.

When `Out-Host` is called *explicitly as part of a pipeline*, however, the table width calculation is skipped for these objects as the object data never makes it to `Out-Default`. This is useful primarily to ensure that object data *intended* to be written to the console is done so in the correct order. The downside is that table columns may not be wide enough to accommodate all of your data on each row.

This all said, if you must process the console output of a script, it is recommended to format the data you wish to process into a string and use `Write-Host` instead, or use another method to get the data somewhere suitable for external processing. `for-display` formatting is not intended for use with external processing.

[@mklement1's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/584676) dives further into the details about this if you are curious to learn more about this problem.

## Redirecting whole command outputs to `Write-` cmdlets

You can easily pipe all output of a command or cmdlet to one of the `Write-` cmdlets. I'll use the `Write-DifferentOutputs` provided earlier in my example below, but this will work with any cmdlet, script, or command you run:

```
Write-DifferentOutputs *>&1 | Write-Verbose
```

What the above will do is only show the command output if `$VerbosePreference = $Continue`, or if you passed `-Verbose` as an argument to your script or function.

## In Summarium

In your original question, you are attempting to reinvent a wheel that Powershell already supports fairly well. I would suggest that you learn how to make use of the different [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) cmdlets for each stream and especially learn how to make use of the [`Write-Warning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-warning), [`Write-Verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose), [`Write-Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-error), and [`Write-Debug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-debug) cmdlets.

Comment: So what you suggest is to modify every output in the code every time I need to switch?
Well I hope I misunderstand than.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe I reinvented a three wheeler and you were suggesting a wheel.
Just maybe.
But thank you anyway, with that bachelor thesis you've posted here for no reason apparent to me, you hyped me to solve it.
And I mean it. Thank you

Comment: That's a good analogy. Your theoretical approach isn't wrong, but it's a problem that is already solved with a first-party solution. I did delve pretty deeply into things, but I think what you will want to use for your case is `Write-Verbose`, which is controlled with the `-Verbose` parameter (as mentioned you'll want to add the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute to the function or script definition) or set `$VerbosePreference`).

Comment: Hi. I don't remember at all,what was I trying to solve back then. However I'm asking about how to suppress output and you're telling me not to send it. So what was the answer to my question? That it can't be done?

Comment: No, it can be done and there are times when you want to redirect output. The answer above explains how to handle redirection and how to use both redirection and the different `Write-` cmdlets to write to each different stream. However, the way you described the use case in your question was that you were trying to re-implement a logging framework that already exists in PowerShell. But, if you just want to suppress the output of a command, you can redirect to `$null` (`> $null`), pipe to `Out-Null` (`| Out-Null`), or cast to `[void]` (`[void]( Some-Command )`).

Answer (score 0):

All right.
Thanks to all the brainiacs here for the motivation.
**This answer may not be the best way to go about it, but it works!**

Two things you need to understand to achieve this:

1. If you are used to using `Write-Host`, it won't work, you'll have to go with `Write-Output`.
2. You may have to learn to use a block of script as a function parameter.

One is self explanatory, so here's how to attain #2:

```
Function Test-SctiptBlockParam {
  Param(
    $scriptblock
  )
  if ($debugOutput) {
    Invoke-Command $scriptblock
  } else {
    (Invoke-Command $scriptblock) > $null
  }
}

Test-SctiptBlockParam -scriptblock { Write-Output "I want to see on the STDOUT sometimes" }
```

Finally, here is an example of my [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvG6i.png) and [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRphW.png)

Comment: You don't need to use a script block like this. Replace `$debugOutput = $true` with `$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'`, and just call `Write-Verbose` instead of `Write-Output`. That said, if you wanted to improve your code to redirect all streams and not just the success stream to `$null`, replace the `>` with `*>` to redirect ***all*** output streams to `$null`. Then it doesn't matter which `Write-Output` cmdlets are used in the script block.

Comment: All right, I don't understand.
I take away my switch: $debugOutput = $true
that has two states on and off

I replace it with $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
Which is my switch?
In which state?
What's does the other state looks like?

Comment: In the meantime I found a specific case in which my design doesn't work.

If you call external script this way, in which you call write-output:
a) from the scripts body or core or whatever, but not from withing a function - it works
b) from withing a function - it doesn't work
:(

Comment: I've updated my answer with a sample on how to use the built in output stream cmdlets, optionally writing verbose or triggering debug breakpoints.

Comment: Looking at your update.
That will take me some digesting to figure out all the implications.
It looks very good, but I want to supress output from other people scripts.
I may be able to explain to them to use write-output instead of write-host.
But I will never be able to explain to them to use different ones in different cases :(
But I may be misunderstanding and willl look into it.

Comment: BTW did you somehow make my code look good?
If so, thank you...but also...what does that teach me? ;-)

Comment: All right, I play around a little with your example and I learned a couple of new things.
Write-DifferentOutputs >$null 2>$null 3>$null will supress everything but information stream. That's kind of cool.

I also realized one thing.
Your solution feels to be build about adding channels.
I'm trying to build a solution about supressing channels.
I figured that out when I realized that the first thing I started to do was to figure out how to hide everything your code provided.

And that is my problem.
If I can learn to supress that information channel as well as the others, it's a win.

Comment: And I hit a dead end:
Here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-welcome-to-the-powershell-information-stream/
They say:
The dilemma was how to fix the harmful aspects of Write-Host (can't suppress, capture, or redirect)

Comment: Yes you can, with `6>$null` or `*>$null`, the latter will redirect all streams. See the stream identifiers in my answer, those numbers consulate to the stream identifiers and can be used when redirecting.

Comment: Note you can also pipe command output to the `Write-` cmdlets, like `SomeScript.ps1 *>&1 | Write-Verbose`, which means you can still control whether they output using the verbose flag or preference variable.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a section on redirecting streams to `$null` or `Out-Null`