# Trying to loop a set of commands in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am new to scripting in general and am trying to tackle the task of writing a PowerShell script to automate accepting RSA keys from PuTTY across some 15,000 servers in my organization.  I have the servers saved in a .bat file and when running that it will auto login through PuTTY.  The issue is when it logs in A RSA security window will pop up requiring me to hit "y"  I have that part and closing PuTTY so the next instance will be loaded, the only issue is I cant get the process to loop.  I am looking for some guidance on the issue.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 



#Variables
$batFile = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\UID\OneDrive - CompanyA\PS Scripts\puttyRSA.bat";
New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;


#opens the "puttyRSA.bat" file

$batFile

#Loops everything
do{

# Will click "Y"
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('title of the application window')
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
$wshell.SendKeys('y')

#Waits and closes putty
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
Stop-Process -name putty
}
While (-FilePath puttyRSA.bat=running)here
```

Comment: What condition are you trying to loop until? `While (-FilePath puttyRSA.bat=running)here` is not valid PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep running until `$batFile` finishes, your `while` clause isn't valid PowerShell. You'll have to make two changes here.

First, you'll need to kick off `$batFile` with [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7) so you can get the PID to wait on:

```
# -PassThru is required because by default Start-Process doesn't return an object
$processId = ( Start-Process -FilePath $batFile -PassThru ).Id
```

Then, for your `while` clause:

```
} while ( Get-Process -Id $processId 2>$null )
```

This will keep your loop running until the process belonging to `$batFile` ends. The `2>$null` redirects the error stream to `$null`, so it won't display an error when the process can no longer be found.

You can read more on output streams and redirection on [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615047/584676).

Comment: Thanks for the help on this!  The script works like charm now!