# Converting batch commands with Powershell that finds files and create parameters

Tags: powershell

In a `cmd` window I search for a specific file then pass it into an executable. I want to redo this using PowerShell, with similar constraints on being on a single line or two independent and separate lines, but being new I can't figure it out.

```
 cmd /r dir /s /b RunnerUnitTest.dll | findstr /r bin\\ > tests_list.txt
 cmd /r for /f %f in (tests_list.txt) do vstest.console.exe "%f"
```

The first command looks for a file, it finds two:

> RunnerUnitTest\bin\Debug\RunnerUnitTest.dll
>
> RunnerUnitTest\obj\Debug\RunnerUnitTest.dll

then it narrows it down to one (bin in the path) and sticks it into a file:

RunnerUnitTest\bin\Debug\RunnerUnitTest.dll

The second line takes this output and passes it into an executable as a parameter.

This is for a gitlab runner, btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this without an intermediate file, since `Get-ChildItem` will return a [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) object for files, and [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.8) objects for directories (both of which are derived from [`FileSystemInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo?view=netframework-4.8)):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse bin\Debug\RunnerUnitTest.dll | Select-Object -First 1 | Foreach-Object {
  vstest.console.exe $_.FullName
}
```

What this will do is recursively search for all files found named `RunnerUnitTest.dll` with parent folders `Debug` and `bin`, and then for each file returned (I've added a `Select-Object -First 1` to ensure we only get one assembly back but this is optional) pass the full path to the assembly to the `vstest.console.exe` program.

The way it's written above, the assembly under the `obj` folder won't be returned at all for execution consideration.

---

As an FYI, piping with `|` works much in the same way as it does with other shells like `Bash` or `cmd`, but it supports passing around complex objects instead of strings. As a general rule, you can pipe any output on the [output stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615047/584676) to other cmdlets or save the output to variables. [Redirection operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615047/584676) work similarly as well.

Comment: Superb thanks. Works a treat. The only 'issue' but I can live with it is my old code didn't need the path to the file putting in, i could just put a search word, e.g. 'bin' and it would find the right one.

Comment: Sure, but what happens when you also have a Release build or some other named build configuration also existing under the `bin` folder? Which one will it pick?