# Powershell function string return value includes more than desired/expected

Tags: powershell

Why does the simplified function below return more than the fruit name in the returned string?

For example, the write host **INSIDE** the function shows a fruit name.
However the write host at the bottom (**outside** the function) shows fruit name (as expected) plus the database connection info (which is NOT desired/expected)

```
    #inside the function, write-host shows a fruit name as expected
    #outside the function (bottom line below) write-host shows extra things such as the connection string (for example: "server=myserver;database=mydb;userid=myuser....thefruitname")
    
    function Get_A_SINGLE_FRUIT_NAME{
        $queryString = "SELECT top 1 fruitname from FROM fruits"; 
        $dbConnectionString = "a-real-conn-string-was-here"   

        $dbConnectionString

        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $edwConnectionString -Query $queryString -MaxCharLength 50000 -OutVariable sqlReturn |Out-Null   
    
        foreach($queryResultRow in $sqlReturn){
            try{
                [String]$returnString = $queryResultRow.fruitname
                write-host("fruitname found:"+$returnString);
            }Catch{
                $_.Exception.Message
                $returnString="No fruitname found"
            }
            Break
        }
        return $returnString 
    }


$qryOut = Get_A_SINGLE_FRUIT_NAME
write-host("qry out:"+$qryOut);
```

Comment: Can you provide sanitized sample output of `Write-Host "qry out: $qryOut"`?

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue. When a PowerShell function returns a value, it also returns any other values output to the pipeline which may have occurred inside the function before the `return` statement.

See also: [Function return value in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286164/function-return-value-in-powershell)

So I removed the extraneous line which contained **ONLY** `$dbConnectionString`, and now the function returns **ONLY** the expected value.

Comment: I was thinking something like this was the problem, though I was thinking perhaps `Invoke-SqlCmd` might return connection information. In this case it was the `$dbConnectionString` variable which was omitted in your original sample.

Comment: I suggest reading this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615047/584676) to learn about output streams and redirection. You can use additional cmdlets to display information on the screen that isn't operable (without some tweaking) programmatically. E.g. you could display your connection string if you want without having it returned via the pipeline and assigned to your variable.