# Powershell - print the list length respectively

Tags: arrays, list, powershell, indexing

I want to write two things in Powershell.
For example;
We have a one list:

```
$a=@('ab','bc','cd','dc')
```

I want to write:

```
1 >> ab
2 >> bc
3 >> cd
4 >> dc
```

I want this to be dynamic based on the length of the list.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: `1..$a.Length |% {"$_ >> $($a[$_-1])"}`. I'm not making that an answer because it's near impossible to understand if you're a beginner and there are more obvious, explicit ways of doing it, but it might be fun to take apart and see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop so you can keep track of the index:

```
for( $i = 0; $i -lt $a.Count; $i++ ){
  "$($i + 1) >> $($a[$i])"
}
```

---

To explain how this works:

- The `for` loop is defined with three sections, separated by a semi-colon `;`.

  - The first section declares variables, in this case we define `$i = 0`. This will be our index reference.
  - The second section is the condition for the loop to continue. As long as `$i` is **less than** `$a.Count`, the loop will continue. We don't want to go past the length of the list or you will get undesired behavior.
  - The third section is what happens at the end of each iteration of the loop. In this case we want to increase our counter `$i` by 1 each time (`$i++` is shorthand for "increment `$i` by 1")
  - There is more nuance to this notation than I've included but it has no bearing on how the loop works. You can read more here on [Unary Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#unary-operators).
- For the loop body itself, I'll explain the string

  - Returning an object without assigning to a variable, such as this string, is effectively the same thing as using `Write-Output`.

    - In most cases, `Write-Output` is actually optional (and often is not what you want for displaying text on the screen). [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615047/584676) goes into more detail about the different `Write-` cmdlets, output streams, and redirection.
  - `$()` is the [sub-expression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#subexpression-operator--), and is used to return expressions for use within a parent expression. In this case we return the result of `$i + 1` which gets inserted into the final string.

    - It is unique in that it can be used directly within strings unlike the similar-but-distinct [array sub-expression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#array-subexpression-operator--) and [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#grouping-operator--).
    - Without the subexpression operator, you would get something like `0 + 1` as it will insert the value of `$i` but will render the  `+ 1` literally.
  - After the `>>` we use another sub-expression to insert the value of the `$i`<sup>th</sup> index of `$a` into the string.

    - While simple [variable expansion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.1#variable-substitution) would insert the `.ToString()` value of array `$a` into the final string, referencing the *index* of the array must be done within a sub-expression or the `[]` will get rendered literally.

---

[Your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69227745/584676) using a `foreach` and doing `$a.IndexOf($number)` within the loop *does* work, but while `$a.IndexOf($number)` works to get the current index, `.IndexOf(object)` works by iterating over the array until it finds the matching object reference, then returns the index. For large arrays this will take longer and longer with each iteration. The for loop does not have this restriction.

Consider the following example with a much larger array:

```
# Array of numbers 1 through 65535
$a = 1..65535

# Use the for loop to output "Iteration INDEXVALUE"
# Runs in 106 ms on my system
Measure-Command { for( $i = 0; $i -lt $a.Count; $i++ ) { "Iteration $($a[$i])" } }

# Use a foreach loop to do the same but obtain the index with .IndexOf(object)
# Runs in 6720 ms on my system
Measure-Command { foreach( $i in $a ){ "Iteration $($a.IndexOf($i))" } }
```

Another thing to watch out for is that while you can change *properties* and execute methods on collection elements, you can't change the element values of a non-collection collection (any collection not in the `System.Concurrent.Collections` namespace) when its enumerator is in use. While invisible, `foreach` (and relatedly `ForEach-Object`) implicitly invoke the collection's `.GetEnumerator()` method for the loop. This won't throw an error like in other .NET languages, but IMO it should. It will appear to accept a new value for the collection but once you exit the loop the value remains unchanged.

This isn't to say the `foreach` loop should never be used or that you did anything "wrong", but I feel these nuances should be made known before you *do* find yourself in a situation where a better construct would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Okey,

I fixed that;

```
$a=@('ab','bc','cd','dc')
$a.Length

foreach ($number in $a) {
    $numberofIIS = $a.IndexOf($number)
    Write-Host ($numberofIIS,">>>",$number)

    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Bender's answer is great, but I personally avoid `for` loops if at all possible.  They usually require some awkward indexing into arrays and that ugly setup...  The whole thing just ends up looking like hieroglyphics.

With a `foreach` loop it's our job to keep track of the index (which is where this answer differs from yours) but I think in the end it is more readable then a for loop.

```
$a = @('ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'dc')

# Pipe the items of our array to ForEach-Object
# We use the -Begin block to initialize our index variable ($x)
$a | ForEach-Object -Begin { $x = 1 } -Process {
    # Output the expression
    "$x" + ' >> ' + $_

    # Increment $x for next loop
    $x++
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------

# You can also do this with a foreach statement
# We just have to intialize our index variable 
# beforehand

$x = 1
foreach ($number in $a){
    # Output the expression
    "$x >> $number"

    # Increment $x for next loop
    $x++
}
```

Comment: Each loop type has its uses. Foreach and foreach-object also work, but I find it awkward to define an counter outside of the loop personally. But this is largely a preference thing. A for loop is also the only way (AFAIK aside from using a concurrent collection) if you do want to modify the collection within the loop.

Comment: Curiously, modifying a foreach loop element does *not* result in an exception unlike C#, though the new value essentially doesn't persist outside of the loop