# How can I create multiple files using a single command on windows command line?

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, cmd

The command for creating a new file on windows using cmd is:

```
cd.> filename.txt
```

But how can I create more than one file using a single command?

Comment: BTW: The command `cd.> filename.txt` is of invalid syntax. There is a space character missing between the command `cd` (argument 0) and the directory name `.` (current directory). So correct would be `cd .> filename.txt` or `cd .>filename.txt`. `cd.` results in accessing the file system searching for a file with name `cd`. The dot at end is removed by the Windows file IO functions as described by the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

Comment: If there is in current directory really a folder with name `cd` or a file with name `cd` which is not an executable, the usage of `cd.> filename.txt` instead of `cd .>filename.txt` results on execution in the error message "*'cd.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*" Please use always a space between the name of an internal command and its (first) argument to make sure that `cmd.exe` recognizes always from the beginning the internal command and does not access the file system to find an executable or script file with name consisting of ...

Comment: ... internal command name and its first argument not separated with a space as required by syntax of `cmd.exe`. The usage of `cd.` works just due to automatic error correction on `cmd.exe` not finding in file system an entry with name `cd` and so starts analyzing what could be the reason and detects now that the user means its internal command `cd` with the argument `.`.

Comment: What about `for /L %I in (1,1,4) do rem/> "file%I.txt"`?

Answer (score 4):

With PowerShell you can use [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.2) with an array of filenames.

> **Note:** `ni` is a built-in alias for `New-Item`, which is useful to substitute interactively.

```
# New-Item
ni fileA.txt, fileB.txt, filec.txt, "file_with_a_${var}_in_it.txt"
```

You can also use `New-Item` to create directories, but a shorter way to do this is to use `mkdir` instead, which is a built-in "alias" function for essentially calling `New-Item -ItemType Directory`:

```
# New-Item -ItemType Directory
mkdir dirA, dirB, dirC
```

### Some tips

- If you want to suppress the output, you can pipe or redirect the output. Add `| Out-Null` or
  `> $null` to either example above (errors and [other streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610934/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-variable-up-to-place-output-to-stdout-or-null/58615047#58615047) will still show as written).
- Both commands support fully-qualified paths and relative paths. You can provide a single string if you are only creating one item.
- You can add as many array elements as you would like, just separate each element in the array with a comma `,`. You can also provide an array variable instead if you need.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to generate a series of files with powershell. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
1..9 |
    ForEach-Object {
        New-Item -Path $env:TEMP -Name ('FileNumber_{0}.txt' -f $_) -ItemType 'File'
        }
```

what it does ...

- generates a number range
- pipes each number to the `New-Item` cmdlet
- uses the `-f` string format operator to build the file name
- creates the file

truncated output ...

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2022-02-03   1:10 PM              0 FileNumber_1.txt

[*...snip...*] 

-a----        2022-02-03   1:10 PM              0 FileNumber_9.txt
```

if you want to get rid of the output to the screen, add `$Null =`  in front of the `New-Item` line.