# How do I copy the ouput of a powershell console into a text file?

Tags: powershell

What I am trying to do is to capture everything in a powershell script and save it in a text file. I would like it as if I manually selected all, copied, then pasted in a text file.

I have explored `Start-Transcript`, but it does not show the `Read-Host`'s. The only solutions I can think of is to `Write-Host` right after every time I use `Read-Host`. Is there any other way?

Comment: Just an idea: define a function named `Read-Host` in your code that calls the real `Read-Host` and logs its output. Generate the source of a wrapper function like this: `[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create(( Get-Command Read-Host ))` and modify it to log the output of `$steppablePipeline.Process($_)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to set a variable up to place output to stdout or null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610934/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-variable-up-to-place-output-to-stdout-or-null)

Answer (score 0):

**This should work**

$application_name >> textfile.text

**Here is an example**

$ ifconfig >> textfile.text

*'>>" means where the output should be saved*

Comment: Im not sure what this means, so I would have a different ps1 script just to run and transcribe the main ps1 script?

Comment: have you tried the answer I provided?

Comment: Yes, it didnt work.