# Using Select-Object in a script moves on before Select-Object is done

Tags: powershell, select, select-object

With this code:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {samaccountname -like "jsmith*"} | select samaccountname
Read-Host "what's up"
```

Why does my output always ask "what's up" before giving me the list of AD Users?
The issue only occurs if I use *select*.

Comment: Timing of the host interaction and success stream don't operate linearly with respect to each other in a script. Add `| Out-Host` after your `select` command to use the host for both interactions. The host won't wait for the pipeline to finish.

Comment: As I was fiddling, I also noticed that piping to Format-Table makes it wait, but I don't always want to use Format-Table.  Thanks for your suggestion of Out-Host.  I'll try that.

Comment: `Out-Host` is only an option if you're outputting to the _display_, unfortunately - see the accepted [answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375) for background information and trade-offs.