# What causes the output of select-object to be truncated?

Tags: powershell, output

I have the following silly PowerShell script:

```
$username = 'rny'

$null = mkdir "c:\Users\$username\YYY"
$null = mkdir "c:\Users\$username\YYY\TODO"
$null = mkdir "c:\Users\$username\YYY\TODO\2021-12-22_Foo-bar-baz-etc"

$files = "C:\Users\$username\one-two-three-four.sql.wxyz",
         "C:\Users\$username\YYY\TODO\2021-11_29_abcdefghijklmnop.wxyz",
         "C:\Users\$username\YYY\TODO\2021-12-22_Foo-bar-baz-etc\another-filename.wxyz"

foreach ($file in $files) {
   $null = new-item $file
}

  Get-ChildItem . -errorAction silentlyContinue -recurse -filter *.wxyz | select-object fullName 

foreach ($file in $files) {
    remove-item  -literalPath $file
}

rmdir "c:\Users\$username\YYY\TODO\2021-12-22_Foo-bar-baz-etc"
rmdir "c:\Users\$username\YYY\TODO"
rmdir "c:\Users\$username\YYY"
```

When I execute it, the output of the `get-childItem ... | select-object` pipeline is truncated:

```
FullName
--------
C:\Users\rny\one-two-three-four.sql.wxyz
C:\Users\rny\YYY\TODO\2021-11_29_abcdefghijklmnop.wxyz
C:\Users\rny\YYY\TODO\2021-12-22_Foo-bar-baz-etc\an...
```

Note especially the last line. This behaviour was noted [elsewhere on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1049531/how-to-fix-truncated-powershell-output-even-when-ive-specified-width-300) and the accepted answer is to pipe the output into `format-table` with `-autoSize`. So far, so good.

However, If I comment the second file in the assignment of the `$files` array like so

```
$files = "C:\Users\$username\one-two-three-four.sql.wxyz",
#        "C:\Users\$username\YYY\TODO\2021-11_29_abcdefghijklmnop.wxyz",
         "C:\Users\$username\YYY\TODO\2021-12-22_Foo-bar-baz-etc\another-filename.wxyz"
```

the output is not truncated anymore:

```
FullName
--------
C:\Users\rny\one-two-three-four.sql.wxyz
C:\Users\rny\YYY\TODO\2021-12-22_Foo-bar-baz-etc\another-filename.wxyz
```

This puzzles me because the name of the file that was truncated is now fully visible and I have no explanation for this.

So, what exactly causes the truncation of the file in one case and not in the other case?

Comment: If you use `-ExpandProperty FullName` for instance you'll see a difference in the output as well as if you save your result from `Get-ChildItem` to a variable before running `Select-Object`. Sorting your output `... | <sort-object> | <select-object>` would also affect the output. This obviously isn't an answer to your question since I can't back it up with anything official, but one might be led to assume it's a matter of decision making for Select-Object, based on some portion of the input when the complete input is unknown.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` seem to be missing before `-errorAction`. I believe what you're experiencing is most likely related to ETS properties. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.2 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add some background to [mcclayton's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70698984/45375):

Specifically, you're seeing the **effects of the infamous 300-msec. delay built into [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) formatting**, which PowerShell *implicitly* applies to instances of .NET types that have 4 or fewer properties and do not have explicit formatting data associated with them.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375) for details (which is given in the context of a *different symptom of the same problem*, namely unexpected output *ordering*), but the short of it is: **The delay is used to infer *suitable column widths* from the specific property values received within the delay period**.

This means that **objects with property values received *after* the 300-msec. delay may be *truncated* in their column display if their values happen to be *wider* than the widest among the values received *during* the delay period**.

Specifically, your symptom implies that only the *first two* objects were received within the delay period, and that the longer among the two property values then locked in the column width; when the *third* object was received later, the column width was already locked in, and the longer value was truncated (indicated with trailing `...` in Windows PowerShell (3 `.` chars.) and `…` in PowerShell (Core) 7+ (single char))

**The only way to *avoid truncating* is to *know the max. column width ahead of time* and pass it to an *explicit* `Format-Table` call -

notably, this prevents using the output *as data*.** See below.

---

Here's a **simple way to provoke the problem**:

<sup>Note: The `Select-Object` calls below aren't strictly needed, but are provided for symmetry with the question.</sup>

```
# Create blocks of two objects with strings of different length in their 
# .Prop value: 10 chars. vs. 100 chars.
$count = 10000 # How often to repeat each object in a row.
$objs = 
 (, [pscustomobject] @{ Prop = ('x' * 10) } * $count) + 
 (, [pscustomobject] @{ Prop = ('y' * 100) } * $count)

# Depending on the value of $count - which translates into how
# long it takes until the second block of objects starts emitting -
# truncation will occur or not.
$objs | Select-Object Prop
```

With blocks of `10,000` objects, I do see the truncation: it takes long enough for the first block - with the short property value - to lock in the width of the display column, causing the objects in the second block to be truncated:

```
Prop
----
xxxxxxxxxx
...
yyyyyyyyy…  # <- truncated, because width 10 was locked in during the delay
...
```

To **prevent truncation**, pass a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) to `Format-Table` specifying the max. width:

```
$objs | Select-Object Prop | Format-Table @{ n='Prop'; e='Prop'; width = 100 }
```

Answer (score 7):

This isn't so much to do with `Select-Object` per se - it's more to do with how PowerShell converts values into string representations, and specifically in this case how it does that when it displays uncaptured output from cmdlets on the console.

PowerShell (Windows *and* Core) has a bunch of preconfigured "views" that define how some built-in types are rendered - e.g. whether they use `Format-List` or `Format-Table`, what properties to display, and in the case of tables, how wide to display each column - see [about_Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.2).

For other types, PowerShell tries to make a best-guess on the fly. To do that it waits for the first N items in arrive from the input to make a decision on the formatting rules to apply. I can't find any definitive documentation that says how many items PowerShell waits for, so that might be a good follow-up question :-).

And you can obviously override these defaults by passing formatting parameters for `Format-Table` and `Format-List`.

In your case the top-level script has received pipeline output containing an array of `PSCustomObject` objects (i.e. the output from `Select-Object`) and it's decided to show them in a table with a column for the `FullName` property.

**Example 1**

In your first example, it's looked at the first two PSCustomObject items and decided to make the `FullName` column 54 characters wide since that's the length of `C:\Users\rny\YYY\TODO\2021-11_29_abcdefghijklmnop.wxyz`, and the third item gets truncated to that *same* width (if you include the `...`) because it wasn't included in the decision-making process for column widths.

```
FullName
--------
C:\Users\rny\one-two-three-four.sql.wxyz
C:\Users\rny\YYY\TODO\2021-11_29_abcdefghijklmnop.wxyz
C:\Users\rny\YYY\TODO\2021-12-22_Foo-bar-baz-etc\an...
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^| 54 characters
```

**Example 2**

In your second example, PowerShell sees the longest FullName property in the first couple of PSCustomObjects is `C:\Users\rny\YYY\TODO\2021-12-22_Foo-bar-baz-etc\another-filename.wxyz` and so uses a column width of 70.

```
FullName
--------
C:\Users\rny\one-two-three-four.sql.wxyz
C:\Users\rny\YYY\TODO\2021-12-22_Foo-bar-baz-etc\another-filename.wxyz
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^| 70 characters
```

**Example 3**

Finally, if you do what @notjustme suggests in the comments and add `-ExpandProperty FullName` onto `Select-Object` you get an array of `string` values instead of an array of `PSCustomObject`s which is why you might see PowerShell apply different formatting rules - you don't get a `FullName` header for example because the values are strings not objects with properties, and it's using `Format-List` instead of `Format-Table`.

```
C:\Users\rny\one-two-three-four.sql.wxyz
C:\Users\rny\YYY\TODO\2021-12-22_Foo-bar-baz-etc\another-filename.wxyz
```