# After starting .ps1 , console output doesn't work

Tags: powershell

`"test"` , `Get-ExecutionPolicy -list` ..

the only command before the start is `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process` . whether i then do `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process` , the issue doesn't change .

i found out that it doesn't happen in some cases

- `Get-ExecutionPolicy -list` provides no console output

  ```
  $v = Get-ExecutionPolicy
  if ($v -eq "Bypass") {

      Get-ExecutionPolicy -list
  }

  read-host -prompt "Press Enter to continue..."
  ```
- `Get-ExecutionPolicy -list` provides the output, kind of

  ```
  Get-Item -Path Env:*

  $v = Get-ExecutionPolicy
  if ($v -eq "Bypass") {

      Get-ExecutionPolicy -list
  }

  read-host -prompt "Press Enter to continue..."
  ```

Comment: Try `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List | Out-Host` to force _synchronous_ output, so that it is shown before the `pause` command's prompt - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375) for background info.

Comment: @mklement0 perfect, thanks aloooooot . i was struggling with this issue at different locations, for months .

Comment: Glad to hear it helped; I suggest closing your question as a duplicate of the linked post. On a general note: It's a tricky and obscure problem that I wish would finally get fixed - see  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4594 and, for an even more problematic manifestation, https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13985