# PowerShell: get object properties in a readable table

Tags: powershell

I am trying to display StrongAuthenticationMethods from the azure object (user) in a more readable way inside of the script which will reset the MFA method.

When I call variable $mfa

```
$UserPname = Read-Host "Please enter e-mail address"
$AzureUser=Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "$UserPname"

$methode = $AzureUser.StrongAuthenticationMethods
$mfa = $methode | Select-Object MethodType, IsDefault
$mfa
```

it gives me a nice table:

```
----------           ---------
PhoneAppOTP              False
PhoneAppNotification      True
```

When I try to write-host this variable:

```
Write-Host $mfa
```

It gives me:

```
Write-Host $mfa
@{MethodType=PhoneAppOTP; IsDefault=False} @{MethodType=PhoneAppNotification; IsDefault=
True}
```

How can I display this MethodType and IsDefault properties in the best readable way using
write-host?

Thanks for the information in advance!

Comment: The question is why you need `Write-Host` to begin with ? Your object is being stringified which is why you see that way. There is no need for `Write-Host` at all.

Comment: Without the write-host variable $mfa, I don't see the table at all. The script jumps to the "switch structure", exactly to the last part of the script:

Write-Host "Would you like to reset MFA for the user $UserPname"

if (($methode)) {
       

 $Readhost = Read-Host " ( y / n ) " 
    Switch ($ReadHost) 
     { 
       Y {Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName “$UserPname”-StrongAuthenticationMethods $p} 
       N {Write-Host  "No actions"} 
       Default {Write-Host  "No actions"}
     }}

Comment: In the top level script, outputting a variable will cause it to automatically be sent to a formatting cmdlet like ```Format-Table``` or ```Format-List``` and displayed in the console. Inside a function, doing the same thing will send the value to the output stream of the function as if you'd used ```write-output```. If you want to display the text *on the console* from inside a function you can do something like ```write-host ($mfa | format-table | out-string)``` *but* that should only be used for display / logging purposes and not for downstream data processing.

Answer (score 1):

Write-Host ($mfa | Format-Table | Out-String)

Answer (score 0):

To **print synchronous, *richly formatted* output to the *host*** (display), use the **[`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host)** cmdlet rather than [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host): `Out-Host` uses PowerShell's rich formatting system, whereas `Write-Host` essentially performs `.ToString()` stringification, which often results in unhelpful output.

```bash
# Forces instant output to the display, 
# but note that such output *cannot be captured*.
# Use ... | Format-Table | Out-Host to force tabular formatting,
# but with a custom object with 4 or fewer properties that isn't necessary.
$mfa | Out-Host
```

Judging by your later comments, the reason you want this is the **well-known problem** of the ***situational* lack of synchronization between pipeline output and to-host output** (as well as output to other streams), which **can cause displayed output to print *out of order***.

```bash
# !! Read-Host executes FIRST
[pscustomobject] @{ print='me' }
Read-Host 'Press ENTER to continue'
```

```bash
# Workaround: Out-Host forces instant printing to the display,
#             but note that such output then cannot be captured. 
[pscustomobject] @{ print='me' } | Out-Host
Read-Host 'Press ENTER to continue'
```

The problem is limited to a very specific - albeit common - scenario: implicitly *table*-formatted output for types that do *not* have formatting data defined for them.

- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375) for a detailed explanation.
- See [GitHub issue #4594](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4594) for a discussion of this problematic behavior.