# Script won't run in Switch menu

Tags: powershell, monitor, event-viewer

```
function Show-Menu { #Create the Show-Menu function
    param ([string]$Title = 'Functions') #Sets title
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "`t6: Reboot History." -foregroundcolor white
    Write-Host "`tQ: Enter 'Q' to quit."
} #close of create show menu function

#Begin Main Menu
do
 {
    Show-Menu #Displays created menu above
    
    $Selection = $(Write-Host "`tMake your selection: " -foregroundcolor Red -nonewline; Read-Host)
    
    
    switch ($selection) #Begin switch selection
    {

#===Reboot History===
    '6' {
                $Workstation = $(Write-Host "Workstation\IP Address" -nonewline -foregroundcolor DarkGreen) + $(Write-Host "(Use IP for remote users)?: " -NoNewline; Read-Host)
                $DaysFromToday = Read-Host "How many days would you like to go back?"
                $MaxEvents = Read-Host "How many events would you like to view?"
                
                $EventList = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $Workstation -FilterHashtable @{
                    Logname = 'system'
                    Id = '41', '1074', '1076', '6005', '6006', '6008', '6009', '6013'
                    StartTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysFromToday)
                } -MaxEvents $MaxEvents -ErrorAction Stop
 
 
                foreach ($Event in $EventList) {

                    if ($Event.Id -eq 1074) {
                        [PSCustomObject]@{
                            TimeStamp    = $Event.TimeCreated
                            Event        = $Event.Id
                            ShutdownType = 'Restart'
                            UserName     = $Event.Properties.value[6]
                        }
                    }

                    if ($Event.Id -eq 41) {
                        [PSCustomObject]@{
                            TimeStamp    = $Event.TimeCreated
                            Event        = $Event.Id
                            ShutdownType = 'Unexpected'
                            UserName     = ' '
                        }
                    }
                }
                pause
        }
    }
    }
 until ($selection -eq 'q') #End of main menu
```

Works perfectly fine if I remove the script from the switch and run it separately, but as soon as I call it from the switch it still asks for the workstation/IP, how many days, and max events, but just outputs nothing.

Here is what it looks like when it works:

```
How many days would you like to go back?: 90
How many events would you like to view?: 999

TimeStamp              Event ShutdownType UserName
---------              ----- ------------ --------
12/23/2022 12:20:55 AM  1074 Restart      Username
12/20/2022 1:00:01 AM   1074 Restart      Username
12/17/2022 12:21:54 AM  1074 Restart      Username
12/13/2022 8:57:40 AM   1074 Restart      Username
```

This is what I get when I run it within the switch menu

```
Workstation\IP Address(Use IP for remote users)?: IP Address
How many days would you like to go back?: 90
How many events would you like to view?: 999

Press Enter to continue...:
```

I have tried just doing 1 day and 1 event, but same results.  No errors or anything indicating a failure, so not sure how to troubleshoot this.  I have had similar issues with switches in the past that were resolved with some researching into scopes, but I don't think this is the same case as it is all self contained within the switch itself.

I am at a loss, any ideas?  As always, any insight into my script is greatly appreciated, even if it doesn't resolve the problem at hand.

Comment: Is the output from the switch maybe getting saved to a variable or discarded making it so that the objects being created never hit the console?  Cannot tell with only the portion of code you provided.

Comment: Dispite the unsanitized amount of code, there is no `switch` statement anywhere in it. Please try to create a [mcve]. See also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'd try `[PSCustomObject]@{ … } | Out-Default`.

Comment: @iRon and Daniel I left the switch statement out as it is only this one in particular that isn't working so the switch is working fine.  I hadn't considered it's hard to test if you don't have part of the code though.

I edited the post to include the switch statement and also removed the extra event id's in the for each statement to make it more compact.

Comment: @JosefZ I tried adding | Out-Default but it creates a table for each of the individual events instead of combining them into one table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) has provided the crucial pointer:

- force *synchronous* to-display output with, such as with [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host)
- if you neglect to do so, the `pause` statement will - surprisingly - execute *before* the `[pscustomobject]` instances emitted by the `foreach` statement, due to the asynchronous behavior of the implicitly applied `Format-Table` formatting - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375) for details.

Here's a simplified example:

```bash
switch ('foo') {

  default {

    # Wrap the `foreach` statement in . { ... }, 
    # so its output can be piped to Out-Host. 
    . { 
      foreach ($i in 1..3) {
        [pscustomobject] @{ prop = $i } 
      }
    } |
      Out-Host # Without this, "pause" will run FIRST.
    pause

  }
}
```

Note:

- For `Out-Host` to format all output *together* it must receive *all* output from the `foreach` loop as part of a single pipeline.
- Since [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) is a *language statement* (rather than a *command*, such as the related [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*) that therefore cannot directly be used at the start of a [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines), the above wraps it in a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) that is invoked via `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-), which executes the script block directly in the caller's context and streams the output to the pipeline.

  - This limitation may be surprising, but is rooted in the fundamentals of PowerShell's grammar - see [GitHub issue #10967](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10967#issuecomment-561843650).
  - An all-pipeline alternative that doesn't require the `. { ... }` workaround would be:

    ```bash
    1..3 | 
      ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject] @{ prop = $_ }  # Note the automatic $_ var.
      } |
      Out-Host
    ```

Comment: What does the ```. {``` do/what is it called?  I wasn't able to find any information expanding on it.  I assume it tells powershell to execute the script within the {...}?
  
This fixed it for me and is outputting exactly as I wanted it to.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, @ThePostMan; my pleasure. Regarding `. { ... }`, please see my update.