# Why Powershell outputting this table?

Tags: powershell

I'm a powershell noob. How come the following code is also outputing the table at the end after the "File to Delete" loop?

```
$stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

# use partial hashes for files larger than 100KB:
# see documentation at: https://powershell.one/tricks/filesystem/finding-duplicate-files#finding-duplicate-files-fast

$result = Find-PSOneDuplicateFileFast -Path '\\READYNAS\Pictures\2020\10' #-Debug -Verbose
$stopwatch.Stop()

# output duplicates
$allFilesToDelete = @(foreach($key in $result.Keys)
    {
        #filters out the LAST item in the array of duplicates, because a file name of xxxx (0) comes before one without the (0)
        $filesToDelete = $result[$key][0..($result[$key].count - 2)]  

        #add each remaining duplicate file to table
        foreach($file in $filesToDelete)
        {        
            $file |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Hash -Value $key -PassThru | 
                Select-Object Hash, Length, FullName                         
        }
    }
)

$allFilesToDelete | Format-Table -GroupBy Hash -Property FullName | Out-String | Write-Host

$allFilesToDelete | Sort-Object -Property FullName -OutVariable allFilesToDelete

$allFilesToDelete | Format-Table -Property FullName | Out-String | Write-Host

$confirmation = Read-Host "Are you Sure You Want To Delete $($allFilesToDelete.count) files? (y/n)"
if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
    $i = 0

    foreach($fileToDelete in $allFilesToDelete)
    {
        $i++
        Write-Host "$i File to Delete: $($fileToDelete.FullName)"
        #Remove-Item $file.FullName -Force -Verbose 4>&1 | % { $x = $_; Write-Host "Deleted file ($i) $x" }
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "User chose NOT to delete files!"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$allFilesToDelete | Sort-Object -Property FullName -OutVariable allFilesToDelete`  **produces output** (the input objects in the requested sort order), and since you're not capturing or redirecting it, it prints to the *host* (display, terminal) by default.

  - It seems your intent is to sort the objects stored in `$allFilesToDelete`, which your command does, but it *also* produces output (**the [common `-OutVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outvariable) does *not* affect a cmdlet's output behavior**, it simply *also* stores the output objects in the given variable);  you could **simply assign the output back to the original variable, which wouldn't produce any output**:

    ```
    $allFilesToDelete = $allFilesToDelete | Sort-Object -Property FullName
    ```
  - In cases where **actively *suppressing* (discarding) output** is needed, **`$null = ...`** is the simplest solution:

    - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) for details and alternatives.
    - Also see [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74945204/45375), which you found yourself.
- **Because the output resulted in *implicitly* [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)-formatted display representations** (for custom objects that have no predefined formatting data), the **subsequent `Read-Host` and `Write-Host` statements - surprisingly - printed *first***.

  - The reason is that this implicit use of `Format-Table` results in *asynchronous* behavior: output objects are collected for 300 msecs. in an effort to determine suitable column widths, and during that period output to *other* [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) may print.
  - The - suboptimal - workaround is to force pipeline output to print *synchronously* to the host (display), using [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host).
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375) for details.

Comment: @crichavin, thanks - please see my update: I've added your link to the answer, along with a link to another answer, but note that the proposed `$allFilesToDelete = $allFilesToDelete | Sort-Object -Property FullName` obviates the need for discarding output altogether.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion! I prefer to remove the unnecessary code.