# Splitting Output in order code is written - Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a powershell Script that retrieves logon data from Servers.
But I cannot get the output to display correctly.

This is the later part of the script that pipes data into two separate arrays and the Output should show the data separately but the output is merging the two arrays together.

This is the code:

```
###Get todays date
$Datestr = $Date.Date.ToString( "dd/MM/yyyy *")

##Display output
Write-Host "All Users logged on today..."
###pipe query into array1
$array1 = $Logonsfound | Select Username, LogonType, LastLogon | Where-Object LastLogon -Like $Datestr | Sort { $_.Lastlogon } -Descending
##Display array1
$array1

####A split should appear here 
Write-Host "`n"

##Display output
Write-host "The Single User:" 
###pipe query into array2
$$array2 = ($Logonsfound | Select Username, LogonType, LastLogon | Where-Object LastLogon -Like $Datestr | Sort { $_.Lastlogon } -Descending)[0]
##Display array2
$array2
```

The output is as follows:

```
All Users logged on today...



The Single User:
Username LogonType LastLogon          
-------- --------- ---------          
user1    Remote    21/02/2023 09:26:26
user2    Remote    21/02/2023 09:16:35
user1    Remote    21/02/2023 09:26:26
```

When I want the output to display like this:

```
All Users logged on today...

Username LogonType LastLogon          
-------- --------- ---------          
user1    Remote    21/02/2023 09:26:26
user2    Remote    21/02/2023 09:16:35


The Single User:

Username LogonType LastLogon          
-------- --------- ---------          
user1    Remote    21/02/2023 09:26:26
```

How do I split the output?

Thanks

Comment: Change `$array1` to `$array1 |Out-Default`

Answer (score 2):

To add an explanation to the crucial pointer Mathias has provided in a comment on the question:

There are **two separate aspects** at play:

- **A script execution's *output* objects** - that is, objects sent to the *success* [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) - are **situationally formatted *together*, even if** they were emitted at different times and are **interspersed with calls that target *other* output streams**.

  - This matters in the case when the for-display output formatting results in ***tabular* output (implicit [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) use)**, where ***all* success-stream output objects** subject to this formatting **end up in a *single* table, irrespective of any intervening calls that target other output streams**, such as [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host):

    ```bash
    # This still prints a *single* table showing *both* objects.
    # See below for the surprising output *ordering*, i.e. for why
    # the Write-Host message prints *first*.
    [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 1 }
    Write-Host "This doesn't impact output formatting of the *success* output."
    [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 2 }
    ```
  - To **force formatted output of *select* objects only and to do so *instantly***, you can **pipe to `Format-Table` *explicitly*** (or any other `Format-*` cmdlet), or - if you want to use the *default* formatting - to **[`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host)**.

    ```bash
    [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 1 } | Format-Table
    Write-Host "The Format-Table calls produce instant, separate table formatting."
    [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 2 } | Format-Table
    ```

    - **Caveat**: In effect, such output is no longer *data*, and is useful *for display only*:

      - With `Out-Host`, the formatted representations print directly to the *display*, bypassing the success output stream altogether, which means that a caller of your script trying to process this data *programmatically* won't see it.
      - With a `Format-*` call, you still send objects to the success output stream, but in the form of *formatting instructions* rather than the original data, and these formatting instructions are only relevant for for-display rendering.
- **With *implicit* `Format-Table` formatting that isn't based on predefined [formatting data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml), the display output becomes *asynchronous*,** and **appears *out of order*** relative to calls that target *other* output streams, notably `Write-Host`.

  - This is the **unwanted side effect of an implementation detail**: PowerShell delays printing a table for 300 milliseconds so that it can look at the incoming data in an effort to determine *suitable column widths*. During this delay, output to *other* streams - even though executed *later* - prints *first*, and even *interactive prompts* execute first. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375) for details, and [GitHub issue #4594](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4594) for a discussion of the problem.
  - Here's a striking example: The `Read-Host` call (which involves printing a message directly to the host) executes *before* the implicitly table-formatted `[pscustomobject]` instance prints:

    ```bash
    [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 1 }
    # !! Because of the asynchronous Format-Table output triggered
    # !! by the [pscustomobject] instance, the Read-Host call executes FIRST.
    Read-Host 'Press Enter to continue.'
    ```
  - The ***workaround* is the same as the one shown above**, and therefore **equally *suboptimal*** in that it makes the script no longer output *data*:

    ```bash
    # Format-Table forces instant output, but makes the script
    # no longer output the the original object, only formatting instructions
    # relevant to for-display rendering only.
    [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 1 } | Format-Table
    Read-Host 'Press Enter to continue.'
    ```

Comment: So, it's just the fact that the objects of the same type are being waited on to display together?

Comment: @Abraham, it is the _first non-primitive success-stream output object_ in a given pipeline / script that determines the output formatting, and if implicit `Format-Table` formatting not based on formatting data is selected, such an object _alone_ introduces the delay - even if all subsequent success output is out-of-band formatted and normally prints synchronously (what I called _primitive_ above, loosely speaking strings and numbers), for instance. Try the following: `[pscustomobject] @{ name = 1 }; Write-Host 'Prints first'; 'out-of-band-formatted success output'`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the clarification.