# Piping to Select-Object with selected fields changes the displayed order in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I noticed that the following:

```
Get-ChildItem; Write-Host "-----------";
```

lists the files **first** and produces the line **afterwards**. The same happens when I pipe the object like this:

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object;  Write-Host "---================---"
```

However, piping with subset of fields changes the displayed order and the line appears **above** the files listed.

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object Name;  Write-Host "---================---"
```

How can I explain the phenomenon?

Comment: Are you looking for this: `Get-ChildItem | %{ $_.Name; Write-Host "----========----" }`

Comment: `Format-Table` (indirectly called) can produce out of order output in certain cases, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/7571258

Comment: @SavindraSingh No. Your sample produces a line under **each** element. I'm trying to get **a single** line below all the names listed.

Comment: Ohh. I think I misunderstood it.

Comment: @zett42 That was it. I'm going to post an answer to my question because I fell that it's more to-the-point'y on my specific issue, while the one you so kindly linked to is a deeper explanations (also a bit harder to google up unless one already knows in what direction it's heading, which to me was rather substantial gotcha).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from @zett42, the error is due unexpected behavior of implicit calls and inner workings of the PowerShell print-outs. The correct approach is to either explicitly state that the output should be piped as a table:

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object Name, Length | Format-Table
```

or as out channel of the host:

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object Name, Length | Out-Host
```

Both approaches have drawbacks as discussed in this [**extensive** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/1525840).