# Converting System.Collections.ArrayList to a string in Powershell

Tags: powershell, formatting

I have the following test script in powershell, the issue I am facing is that I want to store the details of the error in a custom object or a variable as a string, right now the value of the error variable is of type    System.Collections.ArrayList.

```
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$sql" -inputfile $file  -Database test -OutputSqlErrors $true -ConnectionTimeout 10 -ErrorAction Continue -Errorvariable err | Out-Null
```

Now, here is what is strange, if I run

```
$err | Get-Type
```

its of type `System.Collections.ArrayList`

if i run `write-host $err`, it prints out the error correctly, but assigning the value of `$err` to a custom object, then I lose the value but get `'System.Collections.ArrayList'` instead.

```
$error_values += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{ErrorMessage =$err}
```

Now running   `$error_values | select ErrorMessage returns System.Collections.ArrayList`

I just need it to be a simple string, not sure what is incorrect here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Generally, don't use [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) to output *data***, as that won't work; **use it for *display-only* output only**; to output data, use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output), or, better yet, use PowerShell's *implicit* output feature.

  - In your case, `$error_values | select ErrorMessage` *by itself* would not only output the information of interest as *data*, it would also have resulted in *helpful* output formatting.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19754384/45375) for more information.
- **Specifically, even when for-display-only output *is* desired, don't use `Write-Host` to print representations of *complex objects*** (loosely speaking, objects with properties);
  **use [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host) instead**.

  - `$error_values | select ErrorMessage | Out-Host`
  - As an aside: the `select` ([`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)) call is virtually a no-op; I presume what you actually meant was `$error_values | select -ExpandProperty ErrorMessage` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809321/45375) for more information.
  - **`Write-Host` does *not* perform rich output formatting**, whereas PowerShell's *default* display formatting and `Out-Host` do. Since `Write-Host` uses simple `.ToString()` stringification, complex objects usually result in *unhelpful* representations - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58240860/45375) for more information.

**A complete example:**

```
# Create a sample ArrayList, as returned by 
$err = [System.Collections.ArrayList] ('one', 'two')

# Construct a custom object ([pscustomobject]) with an .ErrorMessage
# property that contains the array list
$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ ErrorMessage = $err }

# !! Write-Host results in UNHELPFUL display:
# !! Note how instead of listing the *elements* of the ArrayList
# !! the *type name* ("System.Collections.ArrayList") is printed instead.
PS> Write-Host $obj
@{ErrorMessage=System.Collections.ArrayList}

# OK: Out-Host produces richly formatted *display-only* output.
PS> $obj | Out-Host

ErrorMessage
------------
{one, two}


# OK as well: *implicit* output, *as data* - same representation.
PS> $obj

ErrorMessage
------------
{one, two}
```

Note: **For *direct* to-display output of a collection whose elements are *not* complex objects, `Write-Host` can be helpful if *single-line* output is desired**, because the elements are then simply space concatenated:

```sh
$err = [System.Collections.ArrayList] ('one', 'two')

# OK with collection of non-complex objects to get a 
# *single-line* representation.
# Out-Host and implicit output print each element on its own line.
PS> Write-Host $err
one two
```

You can even use `-Separator` to use a separator other than a space:

```sh
PS> Write-Host -Separator /  'one', 'two'
one/two
```

Of course, you can also use an *expression* to create such a string, using the `-join`, the [string joining operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) operator, which would allow you to use the output *as data*:

```sh
PS> 'one', 'two' -join '/'
one/two
```

---

**Optional reading**: Why a target variable passed to `-ErrorVariable` receives a [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList) instance:

The [common `-ErrorVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#errorvariable) - and indeed all common `-*Variable` parameters that collect a stream's output in a variable - *always* return a [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList) instance with the collected output, which is surprising in two respects:

- PowerShell generally uses `[object[]]` *arrays* as its default collection data type.
- Additionally, in the case of `-OutVariable`, the behavior is inconsistent with *direct* output from the pipeline, where a *single* object output from a command is output *as such* - rather than being wrapped in a collection, such as `ArrayList` in this case; that is, even though you would expect the following two commands to be equivalent, they're not:

  ```
  $out = Get-Date  
  # -> $out is a [datetime] instance.

  # !! -OutVariable *always* creates ArrayList.
  $null = Get-Date -OutVariable out 
  # -> $out is a *single-element ArrayList* containing a [datetime] instance.
  ```

For a discussion of these inconsistencies, see [GitHub issue #3154](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3154).

Answer (score 3):

```
$arrayList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

[void]$arrayList.Add("one")
[void]$arrayList.Add("two")
[void]$arrayList.Add("three")

$msg = $arrayList -join ", "
Write-Host $msg
```