# How to call powershell script from other powershell script and script is assigned in the powershell object instead of the file

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am writing a PowerShell script and I have another PowerShell script.
I know, we can use below code if it is stored in the path

```
$scriptPath = "D:\Ashish\powershell\script.ps1"
$argumentList = "asdf fgh ghjk"
$output =Invoke-Expression "& `"$scriptPath`" $argumentList"
```

but my PowerShell is stored in the object instead of a file. I am using the below code

```
$argumentList = "asdf fgh ghjk"
$logPath = "C:\AshishG\powershell\script21.txt"
$x = 'Write-Host "Hello script2" return "script2"' #This is my powershell script
//Write code here to call this script($x) with params and store the return value in the other object and also store the logs in $logpath
```

The one way could be to store the PowerShell to the script.ps1 but I think, there should be some way to call it from the PowerShell object itself?

Please share your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking for a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$argumentList = "asdf fgh ghjk"
$logPath = "C:\AshishG\powershell\script21.txt"
$x = {
    param($arguments, $path)

    "Arguments: $arguments"
    "Path: $path"
}
```

A script block can be executed using the [call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-):

```
& $x -arguments $argumentList -path $logPath
```

Or the [dot sourcing operator `.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#dot-sourcing-operator-):

```
. $x -arguments $argumentList -path $logPath
```

[`.Invoke(..)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invoke?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) works too however it's not commonly used and not recommended in this context. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59220711/15339544) for more information:

```
$x.Invoke($argumentList, $logPath)
```

---

Yet another option is to call the [`[scriptblock]::Create(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.create?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) method, if the script is stored in strings this is the recommended alternative over [`Invoke-Expression` which should be avoided.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). This is also very useful for example when we need to pass a `function` to a different scope. Thanks [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70457718/how-to-call-powershell-script-from-other-powershell-script-and-script-is-assigne#comment124554873_70457873) for the reminder on this one :)

```
$argumentList = "asdf fgh ghjk"
$logPath = "C:\AshishG\powershell\script21.txt"

$x = @'
"Arguments: $argumentList"
"Path: $logPath"
'@

& ([scriptblock]::Create($x))

# Or:
$scriptblock = [scriptblock]::Create($x)
& $scriptblock
```

Comment: my PowerShell script is stored in $x but you have changed it. I am not clear about your logic. where is the powershell scrip[t in this - & $x -arguments $argumentList -path $logPath

Comment: @AshishGoyanka I have added mklement0's comment, using `[scriptblock]::Create()` which is something similar to what you're doing, the other alternative would be to use `Invoke-Expression` but I would not recommend it.