# How does $_ get set in a ScriptBlock?

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to have a function in script where I can use a ScriptBlock passed in as either a predicate or with `Where-Object`.

I can write

```
cat .\.gitignore | Where-Object { $_.contains('pp') }
```

and this works; as does:

```
$f =  { $_.contains('pp') }; cat .gitignore | Where-Object $f
```

however trying

```
$f.Invoke( 'apple' )
```

results in

> MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Invoke" with "1" argument(s): "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Whereas I expected `True`. So clearly `$_` wasn't set.

Likewise

```
$ff = { echo "args: $args`nauto: $_" }; $ff.Invoke( 'apple' )
```

outputs

```
args: apple
auto:
```

So `$_` is clearly not getting set.

```
'apple' | %{ $_.contains('pp') }
```

Works, but I want the scriptblock to be a variable and

```
$f = { $_.contains('pp') }; 'apple' | %$f
```

Is a compile error.

---

**tl;dr:** So how do I set/pass the value of `$_` inside a scriptblock I am invoking?

Comment: `$_` is automatically set in the context of a `process` block of a scriptblock. Otherwise, you can `InvokeWithContext` method

Comment: You can always write a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note, this answer only covers how does `$_` gets populated in the context of a `process` block of a script block. Other use cases can be found in the [about_PSItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psitem?view=powershell-7.2) documentation**.

---

In the context of a [`process` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#process) of a [Script Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2), the `$_` (`$PSItem`) variable is automatically populated and represents each element coming from the pipeline, i.e.:

```bash
$f = { process { $_.contains('pp') }}
'apple' | & $f # True
```

You can however achieve the same using [`InvokeWithContext` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invokewithcontext?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) from the [ScriptBlock Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0):

```bash
$f = { $_.contains('pp') }
$f.InvokeWithContext($null, [psvariable]::new('_', 'apple')) # True
```

Do note, this method **always returns [`` Collection`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1?view=net-7.0)**. Output is not enumerated.

---

Worth noting as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, the scoping rules of script blocks invoked via it's methods or via the [call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-) still apply.

Script Blocks are able to see parent scope variables (**does not include [Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-7.3)**):

```bash
$foo = 'hello'
{ $foo }.Invoke() # hello
```

But are not able to update them:

```bash
$foo = 'hello'
{ $foo = 'world' }.Invoke()
$foo # hello
```

Unless using a scope a modifier (applies only to [**Value Types**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-04?view=powershell-7.3)):

```bash
$foo = 'hello'
{ $script:foo = 'world' }.Invoke()
$foo # world
```

Or via the [dot sourcing operator `.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#dot-sourcing-operator-):

```bash
$foo = 'hello'
. { $foo = 'world' }
$foo # world

# still applies with pipelines!
$foo = 'hello'
'world' | . { process { $foo = $_ }}
$foo # world
```

See **[about Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2)** for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, `InvokeWithContext()` always runs the script in a new scope.

Comment: @zett42 thats correct, any assignment there is lost unless using a scope modifier, similar to `&` without enumeration

Comment: A way to avoid creating a new scope is the dot-sourcing operator: `'apple' | . $f`. This way it works similarly to `ForEach-Object`.

Comment: @zett42 and I was planning on a short answer zett! what have you done!  hope it looks good now?

Comment: [`$f =  { $_.contains('pp') }; 'apple' | . $f`](https://replit.com/@ArthurBugorski/fails?v=1) does not seem to work.

Comment: @Sled no because there is no `process` block :) only in a `process` block the `$_` is automatically defined.

Comment: Thanks, it's more complete now. @Sled To avoid a `process {}` block in the predicate script block, you could use `ForEach-Object` as demonstrated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75260906/7571258) or write `$f = { $_.contains('pp') }; 'apple' | . { process { . $f }}`

Answer (score 1):

**Using the [`.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invoke?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) method (and its variants, [`.InvokeReturnAsIs()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invokereturnasis?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) and [`.InvokeWithContext()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invokewithcontext?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0)) to execute a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) in PowerShell code is best avoided**, because it changes the semantics of the call in several respects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59220711/45375) for more information.

While the PowerShell-idiomatic equivalent is `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), it is *not* enough here, given that you want want the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) to be defined in your script block.

The **easiest way to define `$_` based on input is indeed [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)** (one of whose built-in aliases is **`%`**):

```bash
$f = { $_.contains('pp') }
ForEach-Object -Process $f -InputObject 'apple'  # -> $true
```

Note, however, that `-InputObject` only works meaningfully for a *single* input object (though you may pass an array / collection in which case `$_` then refers to it *as a whole*); to provide multiple ones, use the pipeline:

```bash
'apple', 'pear' | ForEach-Object $f  # $true, $false

# Equivalent, with alias
'apple', 'pear' | % $f
```

---

If, by contrast, your **intent is simply for your script block to accept *arguments*, you don't need `$_`** at all and can simply make your script **either *formally declare parameter(s)*** or **use the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args)** which contains all (unbound) positional arguments:

```bash
# With $args: $args[0] is the first positional argument.
$f = { $args[0].contains('pp') }
& $f 'apple'


# With declared parameter.
$f = { param([string] $fruit) $fruit.contains('pp') }
& $f 'apple'
```

For more information about the parameter-declaration syntax, see the conceptual [`about_Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions#functions-with-parameters) help topic (script blocks are basically unnamed `function`s, and only the `param(...)` declaration style can be used in script blocks).

Comment: Nice, but piping to a script block with a `process {}` block (as shown by [Santiago's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75260923/7571258)) might be preferable, due to the performance issues of `ForEach-Object`, when it calls a script block.

Comment: Thanks, @zett42, that's worth considering _if and when_ performance becomes a concern, but that is really a separate issue, and the workaround adds additional complexity, whereas my aim here is to explain the fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by wrapping `$f` in `()` like

```
$f = { $_.contains('pp') }; 'apple' | %($f)
```

...or (thanks to @zett42) by placing a space between the `%` and `$` like

```
$f = { $_.contains('pp') }; 'apple' | % $f
```

Can even pass in the value from a variable

```
$f = { $_.contains('pp') }; $a = 'apple'; $a | %($f)
```

Or use it inside an `If`-statement

```
$f = { $_.contains('pp') }; $a = 'apple'; If ( $a | %($f) ){ echo 'yes' }
```

So it appears that `$_` is only set by having things 'piped' (aka `\`) into it? But *why* this is and how it works, and if this can be done through `.invoke()` is unknown to me. If anyone can explain this please do.

From [What does $_ mean in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494115/what-does-mean-in-powershell?rq=1) and the related documentation, it seems like `$PSItem` is indeed a better name since it isn't like [Perl's `$_`](https://perlmaven.com/the-default-variable-of-perl)

Comment: It's not the parentheses in `($f)` but the piping to `ForEach-Object`, which defines `$_` as the current pipeline object. Your sample from the question works, if you insert a space between percent and dollar sign: `$f = { $_.contains('pp') }; 'apple' | % $f`