# How to clear all variables defined in the current loop

Tags: powershell

An operation which assigns something to a variable might fail. We might want to continue despite the failure, but now we have data from the last loop iteration in the variable, leading to unexpected results.

For example in the following code `$z` will not be assigned when `$RAND` happens to be a 0, because division by 0 will throw an error. This causes the `Write-Host` to output the value from last iteration.

```
foreach ($i in 1..10) {
    $RAND = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 11
    $z = $i / $RAND
    Write-Host "Value: $z" -ForegroundColor Green
    Remove-Variable -Name z -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

I want to clear all variables defined in the current loop iteration. I could type them all out manually in the `Remove-Variable` section, which is how I do it right now. But is there a way to determine all variables defined in the current loop iteration?

Comment: You need to use [Clear-Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/clear-variable?view=powershell-7.3) function, It allows you to clear values by mask or all at once.

Comment: Additionally, make the first line in the loop before setting the variable be `$var1 = ""` and then follow that by the `$var1 = Get-Childitem ...` and then follow that with the `Remove-Variable -Name ...` essentially clearing the variable before and after setting it.

Comment: Create a new *scope*, by creating a function or a scriptblock: `&{ $var1 = Get-Childitem ... } <# now $var1 no longer exists #> }`. Variables that are defined in a new scope will be removed automatically when the scope ends. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: To go one step further than @zett42, if your loop code is so complex that you can’t track variable usage easily, maybe refactor into functions instead and call them in your loop. Much easier to reason about, and easier to write Pester tests for (you’re writing Pester tests, right? :-))

Comment: I agree with **mclaytom**.  [Don't use the `<verb>-Variable` cmdlets for dynamic variable names!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68830451/1701026) instead use a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable). See also [Rule request: Warning if `Set/Get-Variable` is invoked with only the basic -Name/-Value parameters](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1706)

Comment: As an aside, your [mcve] isn't clear on how "*This causes the Write-Host to output the value from last iteration.*" as your script will normally stop at a division by zero. How do you continue this? Anyways, I think you actually want to do this: `$z = Try { $i / $RAND } Catch { $Null }`

Comment: @iRon division by zero seems to be a non-terminating error on both PS5 and PS7 for me

Comment: Why not set `-Minimum 1` and avoid the exception?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen this is just an example obviously. In practice my code might have bugs which when I first run into them, I rather have the loop work on empty data instead of previous data

Comment: "*division by zero seems to be a non-terminating error on both PS5 and PS7 for me*" --> **correct**. I was on holidays and not in the position to test and properly respond. Yet, `$z = Try { $i / $RAND } Catch { $Null }` might be a better way to go see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77185524/1701026).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution indicated by @zett42 in the comments (*wrapping the whole loop iteration in a scriptblock*) aka wrapping your code in an (anonymous) function, might be an easy solution as it creates a complete new scope *for every variable* (as indeed questioned) but is rather expensive, see: [What is the best way to reuse static code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75722846/1701026).

Besides, from a coding perspective, it might be better to be specific on the part that might fail and the specific variable that you would (re)set in case of an error. You might do this by using a [Try/Catch block](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally) **and leaving the assignment outside**. Meaning `$z = Try { $i / $RAND } Catch { Write-Error $_ }` and not: <strike>`Try { $z = $i / $RAND } Catch { Write-Error $_ }`</strike>.

```
foreach ($i in 1..10) {
    $RAND = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 11
    $z = Try { $i / $RAND } Catch { Write-Error $_ }
    Write-Host "Value: $z" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

- Note that if there is nothing returned to the [success stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams) in the `Catch` block, an "empty `$null`" (a `System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull`) will be returned which will eventually cause a `$Null` to be assigned to the concerned variable. See also: [Everything you wanted to know about `$null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null#empty-null)

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I agree try catch is preferred and is what I would do to fix the problem when it comes up. Sometimes it is hard to know beforehand which part of the code might error out. For example a file server might be under load and not respond to a delete file request in certain circumstances, while it worked fine when testing the script and therefore one did not think about handling that error

Comment: Also this question only was raised for scripts where I want the loop to continue on purpose. For my usual scripts I define one global `trap` block with `ErrorAction` set to `Stop`. In that trap block I send myself an email with the error. This gives me the most control over what the script did and what steps have to be taken to rectify the problem.

Comment: Which begs the question, would a try catch around the whole loop `foreach (...) { try { # code } catch { continue } }` be more performant than the `&` scripblock method?

Comment: A try/catch around the whole loop will probably faster. Anyhow, generally, I discourage everybody to build large `Try` blocks as it might as well catch *unexpected* errors and the PowerShell error handling is usually a lot better any custom error handling (or a simple `continue` , but you might consider to email the whole current error record: `$_` and than `continue`).

Comment: Good point, I would have to know beforehand which commands could cause a non-terminating but acceptable error and apply a `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to it so it does not trigger the catch block. So it might be better to just let the variables fall out of scope. Anyway thanks for reminding me to read some more details about technicalities in error handling in Powershell

Comment: @DavidTrevor this should be the accepted answer, the self-answer you have provided is not something that could be recommended vs a standard `try / catch` approach. It's also, as iRon pointed out, extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @zett42 in the comments, wrapping the whole loop iteration in a scriptblock causes all variables inside to fall out of scope after each loop iteration.

```
foreach ($i in 1..10) {
    & {
        $RAND = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 11
        $z = $i / $RAND
        Write-Host "Value: $z" -ForegroundColor Green
     }
}
```

Upon error, the output will now be empty instead of repeat the value from the last loop iteration

```
Value: 0.5
Value: 0.333333333333333
RuntimeException: Attempted to divide by zero.
Value: 
Value: 2
Value: 5
Value: 0.6
Value: 0.7
Value: 1.6
Value: 1.28571428571429
Value: 1.25
```

---

However, the performance impact of this method is enormous.

```
Measure-Command {
    foreach ($i in 1..47483647) {
        & {
            $z = $i
        }
    }
}
```

> Minutes           : 2 Seconds           : 36

---

The impact of the Remove-Variable approach is even more extreme

```
Measure-Command {
    foreach ($i in 1..47483647) {
        Remove-Variable -Name z -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $z = $i
    }
}
```

> Minutes           : 13 Seconds           : 2

---

A try/catch around the whole code in the function is by far superior to the other two methods in terms of performance. By a magnitude where I'd say there is no alternative to a try/catch.

```
Measure-Command {
    foreach ($i in 1..47483647) {
        try {
            $z = $i
        } catch {
            continue
        }    
    }
}
```

> Minutes           : 0 Seconds           : 11