# Passing Codeblock to Generic PowerShell Functions

Tags: powershell

I have 2 functions written in PowerShell 5. Each has code that is identical at the top and bottom but the code in the middle varies. Like this simplified version (but more complex in practice there are 9 of them not 2).

```
function Get-PingData {
    param(
        [string[]]$computers
    )
    
    # Generic stuff
    Write-Host "Starting..."

    # Specific stuff
    $resultsArray = @()
    foreach( $computer in $computers ) {
        $result = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet
        $resultsArray += $result
    }

    # Generic stuff
    $output = ( $resultsArray -join "," )
    Write-Host "Done!"
    $output
}

function Test-TCPConnection {
    param(
        [string[]]$computers
    )
    
    # Generic stuff
    Write-Host "Starting..."

    # Specific stuff
    $resultsArray = @()
    foreach( $computer in $computers ) {
        $result = ( Test-NetConnection -Port 3389 -ComputerName $computer ).TcpTestSucceeded
        $resultsArray += $result
    }

    # Generic stuff
    $output = ( $resultsArray -join "," )
    Write-Host "Done!"
    $output
}


$servers = @("server1", "server2")
Get-PingData $servers
Test-TCPConnection $servers
```

The code works but there is much commonality between them. So, I decided to make the function generic and pass a code block each time, like this:

```
function Get-GenericStuff {
    param(
        [string[]]$computers,
        [scriptblock]$sb
    )
    
    # Generic stuff
    Write-Host "Starting..."

    # Specific stuff
    $resultsArray = @()
    foreach( $computer in $computers ) {
        $result = $sb.Invoke()
        $resultsArray += $result
    }

    # Generic stuff
    $output = ( $resultsArray -join "," )
    Write-Host "Done!"
    $output
}


$servers = @("server1", "server2")
$codeblock = { Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet }
Get-GenericStuff $servers $codeblock
$codeblock = { ( Test-NetConnection -Port 3389 -ComputerName $computer ).TcpTestSucceeded }
Get-GenericStuff $servers $codeblock
```

This is much shorter and also works. However, I am very uncomfortable with the fact that the codeblocks include a variable name ("$computer") that is used inside the function: if the function decides, for example, to change the variable name from $computer to $server, the codeblock also needs to be changed and this makes the code liable to break in the future.

This leads me to think that I am going about the problem incorrectly. Is there a better way to do this such that I maintain a single generic function but also avoid this brittleness?

Comment: I think you should create a cmdlet that support [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) input for this. As an aside, [try to avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60708578/1701026) as it is ineffective.

Comment: Yes, fair comment and bad example on my part - I'd actually normally avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

- **Choosing `$_` as the name of the variable** in the input script blocks that will receive input from your  `Get-GenericStuff` wrapper function is indeed a good choice, given the established semantics of the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_).
- However, **I suggest avoiding the `.Invoke()` method** to execute [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) in PowerShell , because - compared to invocation via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), and invocation by *cmdlets* - it changes the semantics of the call in several respects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59220711/45375) for more information.

Invoking a given script block that references `$_` with **[`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) is therefore the better choice**: It automatically passes its pipeline input objects to a given script block one by one, bound to `$_`

A simplified example:

```bash
function Get-GenericStuff {
  param(
    [string[]] $ComputerName,
    [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock
  )
  
  # Generic stuff
  Write-Host "Starting..."

  # Specific stuff
  # NOTE: Use of ForEach-Object ensures that each pipeline input
  #       object is bound to $_, as seen inside script block $sb
  $ComputerName | ForEach-Object $ScriptBlock

  # Generic stuff
  Write-Host "Done!"
}

# Sample call
Get-GenericStuff -ComputerName foo, bar -ScriptBlock { "[$_]" }
```

Output:

```
Starting...
[foo]
[bar]
Done!
```

---

However, note that this approach invariably passes the specified computer names *one by one* to the specified script block resulting in *synchronous, sequential* execution.

This **forgoes the potential for *parallel* execution**, which is typically *built into* cmdlets that accept a `-ComputerName` parameter, such as [`Test-Connection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection)<sup>[1]</sup>

You can address this via an (by definition *optional*) **`-AsArray` switch** that instructs the wrapper function to pass the given computer names *as a single array argument*:

```bash
function Get-GenericStuff {
  param(
    [string[]] $ComputerName,
    [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock,
    [switch] $WithArray
  )

  # Generic stuff
  Write-Host "Starting..."

  # Specific stuff
  if ($WithArray) { # Pass the $ComputerName array *as as whole*
    ForEach-Object $ScriptBlock -InputObject $ComputerName
  } else {
    # NOTE: Use of ForEach-Object ensures that each pipeline input
    #       object is bound to $_, as seen inside script block $sb
    $ComputerName | ForEach-Object $ScriptBlock
  }

  # Generic stuff
  Write-Host "Done!"
}

# Sample call
Get-GenericStuff -WithArray -ComputerName foo, bar -ScriptBlock { "[$_]" }
```

Output:

```
Starting...
[foo bar]
Done!
```

Note how `[foo bar]` implies that *array* `foo, bar` was passed *as a whole*; it is the equivalent of `"[$('foo', 'bar')]"`

---

Finally, note that **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) introduced *general, thread-based parallelism* via `ForEach-Object`'s `-Parallel` parameter**.

Thus, you could extend the function with a `-Parallel` switch (that is mutually exclusive with `-WithArray`):

```bash
function Get-GenericStuff {
  param(
      [string[]] $ComputerName,
      [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock,
      [Parameter(ParameterSetName='WithArray')]
      [switch] $WithArray,
      [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Parallel')]
      [switch] $Parallel
  )

  # Generic stuff
  Write-Host "Starting..."

  # Specific stuff
  if ($WithArray) { # Pass the $ComputerName array *as as whole*
    ForEach-Object $ScriptBlock -InputObject $ComputerName
  } elseif ($Parallel) {
    # Pass each element of the $ComputerName array to a *separate thread*.
    $ComputerName | ForEach-Object -Parallel $ScriptBlock
  } else {
    # NOTE: Use of ForEach-Object ensures that each pipeline input
    #       object is bound to $_, as seen inside script block $sb
    $ComputerName | ForEach-Object $ScriptBlock
  }

  # Generic stuff
  Write-Host "Done!"
}

# Sample call
Get-GenericStuff -Parallel -ComputerName foo, bar -ScriptBlock { "[$_]" }
```

---

<sup>[1] In this specific case, `-ComputerName` happens to be an *alias* of `-TargetName`.</sup>

Comment: [edit] I've now digested this. 1. Yes, I see switching to $_ is preferable. 2. Re not using .Invoke() - oh dear, I think I need to go back an re-write some of my older scripts. ;-) But thanks for pointing that out and the reference, I've noted it. 3. Re using -WithArray, appreciated. Once I get this bit working, parallelising it was going to be the next step. 4. Re -Parallel - yes I read about this (not used it yet), but unfortunately, with this one I am workng with Windows PowerShell (not Core) only. :-(

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Mark: `.Invoke()` may often not be a problem in practice, but using `&` or `. ` (or, as in this case, `ForEach-Object`) not only avoids different behavior in edge cases, but is simpler. Re `ForEach-Object -Parallel`: while a handy option in general, for network/remoting commands with an (array-typed) `-ComputerName` parameter it is better to use the suggested `-WithArray` approach, even in PowerShell 7+

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.InvokeWithContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invokewithcontext?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) with [`$_` (`$PSItem`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#_) as the defined context variable:

```bash
function Get-GenericStuff {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string[]] $computers,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [scriptblock] $sb
    )

    # Generic stuff
    Write-Host 'Starting...'

    # Specific stuff
    foreach ($computer in $computers) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Computer = $computer
            Result   = $sb.InvokeWithContext($null, [psvariable]::new('_', $computer))[0]
        }
    }
}


$servers = @('google.com', 'stackoverflow.com')
$codeblock = { Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet }
Get-GenericStuff $servers $codeblock | Out-Host
$codeblock = { ( Test-NetConnection -Port 80 -ComputerName $_ ).TcpTestSucceeded }
Get-GenericStuff $servers $codeblock | Out-Host
```

The defined variable can be literally anything you would like, `$_` is a commonly used / known variable but it could mind as well be `this`:

```
$sb.InvokeWithContext($null, [psvariable]::new('this', $computer))[0]
```

Then in the Script Block:

```bash
{ Test-Connection -ComputerName $this -Quiet }
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll take a look at this today as well.

Comment: I'm assuming that InvokeWithContext has the same disadvantages as linked to by @mklement0? (In other words, better to use '&' ?)

Comment: @Mark I don't see a disadvantage with using `.InvokeWithContext(..)` for invoking single commands like you're doing